# How to properly mock Picasso into Unit Tests?

Tags: android, testing, mocking, mockito, picasso

As I am trying to conduct the following simple Presenter Test

```
public class NewsPresenterTest {
private static List<News> NEWS_HEADLINES;

@Mock
private NewsRepository mNewsRepository;

@Mock
private Picasso mPicassoClient;

@Mock
private ChromeTabsWrapper mChromeTabsWrapper;

@Mock
private NewsContract.View mNewsView;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<NewsDataSource.LoadNewsCallback> mLoadNewsCallbackCaptor;

private NewsPresenter mNewsPresenter;

@Before
public void setupNewsPresenter() {
    // inject the mocks
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mNewsPresenter = new NewsPresenter(mNewsRepository, new CompositeDisposable(), mPicassoClient, mChromeTabsWrapper);
    mNewsPresenter.subscribe(mNewsView);

    NEWS_HEADLINES = Lists.newArrayList(...);
}

@Test
public void loadHeadlinesNewsFromRepositoryAndLoadIntoView(){
          // verify certain behavior 
    }
}
```

I seem to not be able in mocking `mPicassoClient`, as result getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor3.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
...more 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.<clinit>(Picasso.java:109)
... and more
```

As the stack states, the exception occurs when mocks are being initiated, to be more accurate on this line
`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

**Therefore mocking `Picasso.class` fails. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Picasso class doesn't belong in your presenter. Move the call to Picasso inside your Fragment. Note that this doesn't prevent it from being covered by the test (in a less explicit way):

Previously:

```
newsRepository.getNews(date) 
   .subscribe(news ->
      Picasso.loadImage(news.getImageUrl()))
```

Refactored:

```
newsRepository.getNews(date)
    .subscribe(news ->
        view.loadImage(news.getImageUrl()))
```

Where `view` is the View from Model/View/Presenter and is implemented by your Activity or Fragment. Inside your Fragment or Activity:

```
@Override
public void loadImage(String url) {
    Picasso.loadImage(url);
}
```

Comment: If I may shoot two questions for clarification. 1.Therefore an Image Loading Client should be injected directly into the `View`? and is this considered a good practice? and 2. I thought of injecting the Client into the Presenter so it would be responsible of passing it further to the View, this way the View would be independent of what Image Loading Client receives from the Presenter, is this reasoning incorrect?

Comment: @CatalinGhita these are really good questions that show you have thought about it carefully. Part of the problem is perhaps thinking of the `Picasso` as a client rather than just a view-layer helper. In most of the examples using `Glide` and `Picasso` I have seen just statically reference Glide or Picasso directly inside a ViewHolder, Activity or Fragment.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications - perceiving `Picasso` as a view-layer helper indeed simplifies my reasoning issue. Therefore when testing the View I might need to provide a simple mock implementation of Picasso but this excludes mocking it directly as in the question asked, therefore solving the issue. Even though this was not what I was looking for initially, your answer provided some helpful insights thus I will accept it. Thanks again!